# Can't display output from promise using ejs template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

When I run the following code inside my ejs file:

```
<% practice.screamIt('tony').then((name) => { %>
    <h1><%-`The name you entered is ${name}`%></h1>
    <% return translateIt(name); //puts name as the parameter for next function %>
<% }).then((translate) => { %>
    <h2> <%= `${translate.englishName} is ${translate.spanishName} in spanish` %></h2>
<% }).catch((errorMessage)=>{ %> 
    <% console.log(errorMessage) %>
<% }) %>
```

It just outputs to the screen object Promise. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be running the promise inside my app.get? Any help would be appreacited.

Comment: Your first then needs to return a `Promise`. I don't know what `translateIt` returns, so doing `.then(async (name) => ...` might fix it.

Comment: I was able to fix it by calling res.render inside my promise. I keep forgettin at times that with async, my page is rendering before the data has been compiled for view lol. Im new to this still but im getting there

Comment: Hi @noobcoderiam, could you share your promise with that fixed. Thanks!